# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at or string at

Tags: sql, perl

I've this error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $index in concatenation (.) or string at getdesc.pl line 43, <OctetsIn> line 2.
```

part of my code as follows:

```
my $select_sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Hid,Hostname,IP FROM Devices")
    or die "$dbh->errstr";
$select_sth->execute() or die "$dbh->errstr";
while ( my $row_ref = $select_sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    my $hostname = $row_ref->{'Hostname'};
    if ( $hostname ne 'null' ) {
        my $hid   = $row_ref->{'Hid'};
        my $ip    = $row_ref->{'IP'};
        my $desc  = "null";
        my $index = 0;
        open( OctetsIn, "snmpwalk -v2c -c public $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.18 |" )
            or die "can't exec: $!";
        while (<OctetsIn>) {
            chomp;
            print <OctetsIn> . "\n";
            /IF-MIB::ifAlias.(\S+) = STRING: (\S+)/;
            $index = $1;
            $desc  = $2;
            $dbh->do(
                "INSERT INTO Description (Hid,index,desc) Values ($hid,$index,'$desc')"
            ) or die "$dbh->errstr";
        }
    }
}

close(OctetsIn);
```

What error is there in my code?  anyone knows how to fix the error ?

The error is on the line:

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO Description (Hid,index,desc) Values ($hid,$index,'$desc')") or die "$dbh->errstr";
```

Comment: Take care that you're reading two lines at each occurrence, `<OctetsIn>` is used twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues regarding your innermost `while` loop:

1. You're reading from the filehandle twice when trying to just print the current line:

   ```
   while (<OctetsIn>) {
       chomp;
       print <OctetsIn> . "\n";    # Should be: print "$_\n";
   ```
2. Always verify that your regular expression matched before using capture variables.

   ```
   /IF-MIB::ifAlias.(\S+) = STRING: (\S+)/;
   $index = $1;               # Will be undefined if regex doesn't match
   $desc  = $2;
   ```
3. Use [placeholders and bind values](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) instead of manually including values in a SQL statement:

   Should aim to never interpolate values directly into a SQL statement like below:

   ```
   "INSERT INTO Description (Hid,index,desc) Values ($hid,$index,'$desc')"
   ```

To clean up these three issues, I'd transform your inner while loop to something like the following.

```
while (<OctetsIn>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
    if (my ($index, $desc) = /IF-MIB::ifAlias.(\S+) = STRING: (\S+)/) {
        $dbh->do(
            "INSERT INTO Description (Hid,index,desc) Values (?,?,?)",
            undef, $hid, $index, $desc
        ) or die $dbh->errstr;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi miller, i have try to do as you said,but can't insert any record to my DB and i don't got any error

Comment: Add some debugging statements to ensure that your regex is matching when you think it should.   If you find that it is, then add some [DBI tracing](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#DBI_TRACE) to see what queries are actually being run.

Comment: hi miller,it's my fault,it's working now successfully , but it's will get when index and desc all have value , but i want to get  when index have value and even if desc have no value   ?

Comment: If you want desc to be an optional matching, you'll have to adjust your regex.  However, I can't recommend anything to you because you have provided no information about that spec.  Either way, it sounds like your primary issues with this question are solved, so I would recommend closing the question and asking a new one if you have new issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should test if regex was successful prior to assigning `$1` to `$index`, ie.

```
 # skip to next line if current did not match, as $1 and $2 are undefined
 /IF-MIB::ifAlias.(\S+) = STRING: (\S+)/ or next;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = $1;
```

your regexp doesn't match, so $1 is undef